# What's the easiest way to switch between different senders in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Namely, I'm talking about MAPIFolder, MailItem, and Recipient object types.

-------------------Additional Info-------------------------------------------

Here's some objects I have:

```
Dim w As Outlook.Application
Dim wInbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
```

Comment: Not really ..... more info as to what you want and confirming you are using Excel to automate Outlook would be useful

Comment: I'm still unclear what you what. To send mail on behalf of someone else ("different sender" in question) or to change inboxes, recipients etc

Comment: Send mail on behalf of someone else is probably the one I'm looking for.

Comment: You can use the MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName property. So you are running this code from Excel with early binding to Outlook?

Comment: I think so. I'm actually trying to open a different inbox rather than the default. How would you suggest doing that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for .SendUsingAccount property, for example below from [this article](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/2010/multiple-accounts-and-the-default-account/):

```
Public Sub New_Mail()
Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts
   If oAccount = "Name_of_Default_Account" Then
      Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
      oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount
      oMail.Display
   End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the problem that you are facing? The above code should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you second mailbox is called "Other Person" then you could try this to reference the Inbox that belongs to it (as distinct from the default Inbox)

```
Dim objOl As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set objOl = New Outlook.Application
Set objNS = objOl.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.Folders("Other Person")
Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox")
```